# RTL in DataTable PDF export

Tags: pdf, datatable, right-to-left

The below is fine but with the column containing long text in Arabic the first line became the second line and the second line become the first line:

```js
$('#table').dataTable({
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            text: 'PDF',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible',
                modifier: {order: 'index'},
                format: {
                    body: function (data, row, column, node) {
                        const arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;

                        if (arabic.test(data)) {
                            return data.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
                        }
                        return data;
                    },
                    header: function (data, row, column, node) {
                        const arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;

                        if (arabic.test(data)) {
                            return data.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
                        }
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
})
```

Here is an image of the text:

[image]

Comment: This example from the DataTables web site may be relevant/helpful: [persian ltr to rtl](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/196856/#Comment_196856).

Answer (score 0):

> customize: function(doc) {
> $(doc.document.body).find('table').css('direction', 'rtl');
> $(doc.document.body).find('table').css('text-align','right'); },

This code works for ltr tables to rtl conversion